# has anyone works on JSO :: JABBER Stream Objects...i want sample working example using JSO

Tags: java, xmpp

i want to create xmpp server using JSO :: JABBER Stream Objects..
i have alreasy written some small code to test JSO..
but didnt get much out of it...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against starting with JSO.  Matt hasn't maintained it for years, and he's unlikely to start doing so knowing that you're going to be writing a server.

Instead, why don't you start with one of the several open source XMPP servers written in Java, such as [Tigase](http://www.tigase.org/) or [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp)?